# Has PastryKit been successfully implemented by anyone other than Apple?

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, pastrykit

Has PastryKit been successfully implemented by anyone other than Apple?

This article and others give a detailed breakdown and source code of PastryKit but has anyone actually got their own content into this framework?

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2009/pastrykit-digging-into-an-apple-pie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They never officially released it so I doubt you can simply grab it and use it in your own project. Assume it is (C) Apple.

Comment: Something being used on the web (inside a page) does not mean that you can grab it to use it.

Comment: If there's no explicit statement to the contrary (i.e. a license in a header comment), sure you can.

Comment: You could, however, link to the file on Apple's website.

Comment: And then when Apple decides to retructure their site, your app will break. Not such a good idea probably.

Comment: The absence of any specific clause on a subject is never protection for the little guy, but merely a cease and desist order waiting to happen when the big company's lawyers find a way to lump it under the umbrella of another clause.